# How to return a string value with ncurses?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I've tried `win.inch(y,x)` and `win.instr(y,x)`, even `win.getch()` and `win.getkey()`. None can achieve the detective effect? I've searched through stackoverflow and google, but so far I didn't find the solution. I've already read the curses manual of python. But still can't solve this.

My code:

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.addstr(1,1,'x')
if stdscr.inch(1,1) == 'x':
    stdscr.addstr(2,1,'success')
    stdscr.refresh()

stdscr.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

I've run this piece of code, but no "successs" was show on the screen. I've debug my code for 4 hours last night. And I'm sure I was stuck at this value judge claim " if `stdscr.inch(1,1,) == 'x'`: ". How could I realize my purpose to see if there is a specific string at a coordinate and then do the correspond action?

Comment: "None can achieve the detective effect" - what's the detective effect, and why do you need to achieve it?

Comment: To detect if there is a claimed string at the specific coordinate. I need this to realize a collision detect function in my word dropping game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`curses.window.inch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.inch) returns an `int`, not a `str`.

The following line:

```
if stdscr.inch(1, 1) == 'x':
```

should be:

```
if stdscr.inch(1, 1) & 0xff == ord('x'):
```

or using `instr` (without specifying length, `instr` returns a string that start at the given position to the end of the line):

```
if stdscr.instr(1, 1, 1) == 'x':
```

Comment: I've tried stdscr.instr(1,1) == 'x':  last night, but failed. I thought if I didn't type the third 1, the default length of string is 1. What's wrong there? By the way, about this A & 0xff == ord('x'): stuff. If I use ord('z') here, the 0xff stuff is the same or need to be changed?

Comment: @Mario, the default length for `instr` is not `1`, but `1023` according to [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/378bdb92e5b7/Modules/_cursesmodule.c#l1438).

Comment: @Mario, `& 0xff` used to get only bottom 8 bits.

Comment: With no doubt I'll accept it later. But I was in company now. Where I don't have python with ncurses on my computer. I'll vote it up first, Later when Back home I'll test it, if it works I'll accept it. Thank you indeed for your kind help. @falsetru. In the future I want to be someone like you to help others. And I know saying thanks in the comment is a violation to stackoverflow comment rule. But we are human beings.Dude. Thank you another time.